# Find and replace specific value using SED

Tags: sed

i am trying to match a key=value pair in a line having multiple key=value in a single line. When trying to do it, the value gets replaced with the following key=value getting deleted.

```
sed -e '/<key/ s/key1=.* /key1="70" /g' -i file
```

expected o/p:

```
<key=value key1="value" key2=value key3=value>
```

actual output:

```
<key=value key1="70" key3=value>
```

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part:

```
/key1=.* /
```

means `"key1=" followed by anything, followed by a space`.

Since matching is greedy, it matches as much as it can, which is `"value"[space]key2=value[space]`.

I suggest you change it to:

```
/key1=[^ ]* /
```

which means `"key1=" followed by any number of non-space characters, followed by a space`.